# Posting to a ColdFusion function from angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coldfusion

I have a login form that I'm using angular satellizer  to post to a coldfusion cfc and check if the user account is valid.

I have the angular setup and I can make the post call to the cfc. I'm having some issue reading the data passed to the cfc.

When I dump the content passed to the cfc I get the following.

```
<cfset data = GetHttpRequestData()>
<cfdump var="#data#">
```

When I look on the header content on the dump I have a binary data and when I look at the encoding it says (Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate).

How can I get the content passed to the cfc? My form post has an object with username and password. I can see it using the development tools and clicking on the headers request payload.

I'm using the Satellizer basic login authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
<cfset data = toString( getHttpRequestData().content )>
<cfif isJSON( data )>
    <cfset data = deserializeJSON( data )>
</cfif>
```